# how to submit timer value in a form when click stop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

how can i make this timer to submit form name as in name="time" and send value to $_POST['time'] when someone clicks stop and then the value i can store it into mysql database?

```
    <div id="timer"></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="stopTimer()">Stop</button>

    <?php
    $time = strtotime('01:00:00');
    ?>


   <script>
    var startTime = <?php echo $time;?>;
    //var startTime = Date.now();
    var second = 1000;
    var minute = second * 60;
    var hour = minute * 60;
    var container = document.getElementById('timer');
    
    function stopTimer() {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
    
    function pad(n){
      return ('00' + n).slice(-2);
    }
    
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
      var currentTime = Date.now();
      var difference = currentTime - startTime;
    
      var hours = pad((difference / hour) | 0);
      var minutes = pad(((difference % hour) / minute) | 0);
      var seconds = pad(((difference % minute) / second) | 0);
    
      container.innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
    
    // This only represents time between renders. Actual time rendered is based
    // on the elapsed time calculated above.
    }, 250);
    </script>
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Send it through AJAX.

Comment: Does something not work? I guess you could use a regular form, set an input field's value with the timer (via JS) and "just" submit the form

Comment: @brombeer can you please show me how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

As @brombeer suggested, just create a form like this:

```
<form action="yoururl" method="post">
    <input id="timer" type="number" disabled name="time" value="<?=$time?>" /> <!--here the value is shown-->
    <button type="submit">Stop</button> <!--when you click here time=xx:xx:xx is sent to yoururl-->
</form>
```

You can then access it from JavaScript as `timer` and edit it ad shown in your question